# Alter Claims of Azure B2C JWT After Sign In

Tags: jwt, azure-ad-b2c, claims-based-identity

**TL;DR:** Is it possible to hit the Azure B2C auth server and have it return to a URL on the app (so a full round-trip) a JWT with altered claims? IE not part of signing in - that has already happened and we are using a JWT already.

---

I have successfully set up Azure B2C to use a custom policy that hits a REST API to get extra claims information.

However, I have a certain situation where I want the user to specify a "mode" and have their JWT altered by Azure B2C to set the current mode as a claim.

Basically, the REST API will return something like:

```
{
  "available_modes":"1,2,3"
}
```

And then I want the user to be able to change this so that they can select a mode, eg "2". Is there a way to hit the auth server and have it hit say `https://myapi.com?mode=2`, passing through the username claim to that API endpoint. Then, the auth server would return the JWT that ultimately has been altered to set something like "current_mode" claim value to "2".

This is a somewhat contrived example but I hope it makes sense, would it be possible by a custom claim to have it go off to the auth server and back in one round trip, returning with a new JWT?

Comment: Do you want B2C or your application/api to return new claims? Where/how do you want the user to specify the mode?

Comment: This seems doable. However, I would recommend you share sample JWT (desired outcome along with claims) so it would be easier to add more concrete details. You can pass through the claims that are return by Rest api, but ultimately B2C will issue the final token and can have those additional claims.

Comment: @Alfredo-MSFTIdentity - yes, consider the mode to be like selecting which account to use for your session when you have multiple - I would like that stored in a claim on the user's JWT.

As for where, it would be selecting the mode from within the app after they logged in. Presumably this would redirect to Azure B2C and then back in a round trip and return with a new token.